# SQLServer Database Connection Question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm an SQLServer novice, using version 2005 of the Management Studio to connect to databases and run simple queries.

I have a "simple" query that I run after connecting to database OSRFileXfer (a SQLServer 9 db):

```
SELECT *
  FROM [OSRFileXfer].[dbo].[HRA_Employee] WHERE [RC] NOT IN
 (SELECT [RC]   FROM [SQL01180WTR205].[OSRALL].[dbo].[BudgetCode_RC_View])
```

OSRALL is in server SQL01180WTR205 (an SQLServer v9 db), which I had connected to in another tab.

I get this error:

```
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server 'SQL01180WTR205' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

I don't have rights to make any changes to the database.  I was hoping there's something I can add to my query to make it work, or maybe some crazy workaround.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do without the right permissions.

Ask your DBAs to get the right permissions to query the remote server, or set them up as [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx).

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with the way I called the remote server then?  I wanted to make sure my syntax was correct before requesting anything.

Comment: @Robert - assuming you got all the names right, no nothing wrong.